# busqueda dicotómica/binaria

Tags: java, busqueda, busqueda-binaria

me han pedido que realice un algoritmo que dada una `f(x) = y` en un vector de tipo `double[]` donde dentro de este se encuentran las Y, las posiciones del vector son las X, la cosa es que debo devolver la posición donde se encuentra el cero. Como precondición tengo que las f(x) solo realizan un corte al eje de las X. Este es mi código modificado y me continua dando fallos de ejecución. Si me pueden echar una mano les estaría muy agradecido. El ejercicio esta dentro de la función IndexZ.

```
public class ExDiV {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] v = {-2, -1.98, 0,1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(IndexZ(v, 0, v.length - 1));
  }

  public static int IndexZ(double[] v, int ini, int fi) {
    int meitat = (ini + fi) / 2;
    if(ini == fi) {
      return ini; 
    } else {
      //if((v[meitat + 1] < 0 && v[meitat - 1] > 0) ||(v[meitat + 1] > 0 && v[meitat - 1] < 0) ) {return meitat; }
      if(v[meitat + 1] >=  0) {
        return IndexZ(v,meitat + 1, fi);
      } else {
        return IndexZ(v, ini, meitat);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sería de interés que agregues a tu publicación los errores de ejecución que tengas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He agregado una comprobación adicional para detectar si el valor en la posición meitat es cero. Si es así, se devuelve esa posición.

He corregido la comprobación de si el valor en la posición meitat es mayor o menor que cero. En tu versión del código, si v[meitat + 1] >= 0 se asumía que el valor en meitat era negativo, pero esto no es necesariamente cierto. En la versión corregida, si v[meitat] > 0, se busca en la mitad izquierda del vector, de lo contrario, se busca en la mitad derecha.

```
public static int IndexZ(double[] v, int ini, int fi) {
    int meitat = (ini + fi) / 2;
    if(ini == fi) {
        return ini;
    } else {
        if(v[meitat] == 0) {
            return meitat;
        } else if(v[meitat] > 0) {
            return IndexZ(v, ini, meitat - 1);
        } else {
            return IndexZ(v, meitat + 1, fi);
        }
    }
}
```